# Diazo: if not for if-path

Tags: xslt, plone, theming, diazo

I'm working on a site with multiple theme base on path:

```xml
<rules if-path="//">
  <theme href="index.html"/>
</rules> 

<rules if-path="/news">
  <theme href="news.html"/>
</rules>

<rules if-path="/Members">
  <theme href="news.html"/>
</rules>

...
```

Now I have a rule that I want to apply **if path is not /news**.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now added if-not-path to the development version of diazo. See: https://github.com/plone/diazo

Answer (score 2):

THe release notes of the brand-new version of diazo:

> 1.0rc4 - 2011-11-02 Add support for @if-not and @if-not-content. Add support for specifying mode on inclusion rules. Preserve comments
>   preceding/following html tag in theme. Closes #12249. Fix quote_param
>   to always use lxml.etree.XSLT.strparam. Handle rules file without a
>   theme to allow drop or replace content.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/diazo

> P.S. the solution could be if-path="not(/news)"

Comment: Just to note that the solution is not `if-path="not(/news)"` - that just matches any path that contains the path segment `not(` followed by the path segment `news)`.